# Searching for a transformer for the power board of an Equipe 2400 studio blitz Power/controller

Tags: power-supply, transformer

This is for a photographer friend, feel it would just be too bad to let this beautiful equpiment stay in the closet because of, as far as I can tell, one blown transformer. The unit is made by Bowens in the UK, model BW-2810, but is now obsolete, they will not fix it.

There was a bang from the unit when it went dead. And there are clear soot marks which seem to eminate from  the secondary side of the transformer, and no other visible marks or damage. The transformer sits close to the input 220V AC, but I do not know its specifications. See the images I have uploaded for details.

It has a label which reads (01993) 883214 L45 G3826/2 and on its plastic casing it is written E138x13.6mm , preceeded with a symbol possibly depicting an M and a P or D. Please see pics for details.
I would be extremely grateful for any leads tracking down the specs of this transformer, as well as, obviously, any pointers to where I could get a compatible one. I have tried searching for the above info with no results.
[image: Inside of the Equipe 2400]
[image: Pads for the transformer. Primary side left. Scorch marks on right clearly visible. 2 pins on primary side, 4 on secondary sid]
[image: Markings on the transformer's plastic part]
[image: Transformator before removing it, w/label]

Answer (score 1):

The transformer marking (01993)... is a UK telephone number, [OEP](http://www.oep.co.uk/) is the manufacturer. There's a high chance they will sell you a similar transformer or be able to tell you the specs from that part number.

If you are stuck I would highly recommend http://www.avantipowerrepairs.co.uk as that looks like some serious (as in, potentially dangerous) capacitance in the unit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have sent the manufacturer a request. And you are right, the frikkin capacitors have 2400 uF 500V ratings each...