# What do the markings on this transformer mean? (appears like OMP E138x13.6MM)

Tags: transformer, identification

I'm trying to find a replacement for a burnt transformer for a studio flash light from the 1990s (Bowens Esprit 500) and found [another post about another company's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406958/searching-for-a-transformer-for-the-power-board-of-an-equipe-2400-studio-blitz-p) transformer that had a similar nameplate so that got me wondering whether they might be interchangeable - what exactly is purpose of the markings in the picture, how do you decode them? They look like OMD E138x13.6MM or OMP E138x13•6ΜΜ or something.

[image: A small nameplate saying something like OMD E1 38x13.6MM?]

Comment: Transformers are usually custom-made for each application.  Chances are slim of finding an exact replacement (except from the same model and age of unit.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *What do the markings on this transformer mean? (appears like OMP
> E138x13.6MM)*

**Firstly** this: -

[image]

[Miles Platt](https://www.milesplatts.co.uk/) are an injection moulder based in Leicester, England who make lots of transformer bobbins.

**Secondly**, the bobbin (EI 38 × 13.6) can be found [here](https://www.milesplatts.co.uk/products/coil-bobbins-for-encapsulation/3718_ei-38/plain/n38132): -

[image]

> *got me wondering whether they might be interchangeable*

The bobbins may well be interchangeable but, unfortunately the cores and windings will almost certainly be not.

Answer (score 6):

The EI 38 x 13.6 mm is the size of the transformer bobbin to fit standard EI-38 "E" "I" [laminations](https://www.reallaminations.com/technical.php). The other markings are the manufacturer, perhaps of the bobbin, not necessarily the transformer.

It does not provide anywhere near sufficient information to compare transformers.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest that the marking is "EI 38x13.6mm", which might mean that it's an E-I transformer core of size 38mm by 13.6mm? An E-I transformer core has iron stampings in the shape of the letters E and I, placed together with the windings surrounding the middle line of the 'E'.

Could you measure the core of the transformer and see it its size is approximately 38x13.6mm? If it is, that would confirm the numbers in the markings.

But it tells us nothing about the windings! The core may have been purchased as a generic item without windings, and the manufacturer has added them according to some (undisclosed) specification.